# 2 prompts and I want to alert in relation with those prompts

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have to ask the user (prompt) to please input a digit (from 0-9) and then to input a number, then alert the number of times the digit is repeated in the number.

Here is my code, I do not know how to proceed. I have tried with an array but then I don't know how to continue. I have tried with a for cycle but then I do not know. How would you proceed?

```
let digit_question= prompt("Please, insert a digit")

let number_question= prompt("Please, insert a number")
```

Comment: LIke this?  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-particular-digit-in-a-number/

Comment: yeeeees. I didnt knew that page

Comment: would be great if you could show us those things you tried, and ask us your specific questions about them/tell us why they weren't working.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution that came to my mind is:

```
alert(number_question.includes(digit_question) ? Array.from(number_question).reduce((p,c) => c === digit_question ? p + 1 : p, 0) : 0)
```

But, as dqhendricks states, there's no formal check against inserted number/digit correctness.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't however do anything to ensure that the first input by the user is in fact a single digit, or that the second input is in fact a number.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < number_question.length; i++ ) {
  if ( number_question[i] == digit_question ) alert( 'digit found.' );
}
```